# linq working with database with many tables

Tags: linq

I have a database with answers with many tables. And if possible i don't want to write the same code for each table like that:

```
answersDataContext adc = new answersDataContext();
var a0 = (from p in adc.answersfios
                  where p.userid == userrecord.id
                  select p);

var a0 = (from p in adc.answersdates
                  where p.userid == userrecord.id
                  select p);
```

Upd:question is the following:
i have many tables and if it is possible i want to write something like

```
var a0 = (from p in adc. ALLTABLES
                  where p.userid == userrecord.id
                  select p)
```

Comment: So can you tell us what is your question..?

Comment: what is your question

Comment: Why not simply put the code in a helper or extension method? Perhaps using generics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) for this:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyEntity> GetByUser(this IEnumerable<MyEntity> source, UserEntity userrecord)
{
  return source.Where(w=>w.userid == userrecord.id);
}
```

or generic way for each inherited:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetByUser(this IEnumerable<T> source, UserEntity userrecord) where T: MyEntity
{
  return source.Where(w=>w.userid == userrecord.id);
}
```

and u can use it like:

```
var a0 = adc.answersfios.GetByUser(userrecord);
```

Comment: i am sorry  , but what  should I write instead  <Myentity> ?

Comment: the class contained in source. u used `var a0 = ...` instead of defining the type. so ur entity inside this type